# Non-recursive version of Trie deletion

Tags: c++, trie

So,I was looking for the non-recursive version of Trie data structures deletion in the internet. I couldn't find one. The best I could manage to find was a recursive implementation of trie in [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-delete/) website. Looking at the code for sometime, I thought that I could make the recursive version of the deletion to non-recursive one. Here is my take on it. Remember, I am worried whether I have done effective memory cleanup. Any insight on the overall code structure will also be helpful. Thanks.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node{
    bool isWord=false;
    node* previous;
    node* children[27];
};

void insert(node*& root, string key){
    node *temp = root;
    temp->previous = NULL;
    int keyLen = key.length();
    for(int i=0; i<keyLen; ++i){
        int index = key[i]-'a';
        //If i is the last element
        if(i==keyLen-1){
            //then take notice of it
            //and change isWord to true
            temp->isWord=true;
            temp->children[index] = NULL;
        }
        //If there is no node at a given index
        if(!temp->children[index]){
            //Form a new node
            temp->children[index] = new node;
            //Take notice of the node that it is coming from
            (temp->children[index])->previous = temp;
        }
        //Traverse along the children node
        temp = temp->children[index];
    }
}


bool search(node*&root, string key){
    node*temp = root;
    int keyLen = key.length();
    for(int i=0; i<keyLen; ++i){
        int index = key[i] -'a';
        //If i is at string length
        //and the end the end it finds
        //itself to be true
        if(i==keyLen-1 && temp->isWord==true)
        {
            return true;
        }

        //If a character does not exist
        //in the traversal 
        if(!temp->children[index]){
            return false;
        }
        temp = temp->children[index];
    }
    //If the string is longer then expected
    return false;
}
bool hasNoChildren(node* root){
    for(int i=0; i<27; ++i){
        //If the root has at least one child
        //then return false
        if(root->children[i])return false;
    }
    //else return true
    return true;
}
void remove(node*& root, string key){
    if(!search(root,key)) return ;
    node*temp = root;
    int keyLen = key.length();
    for(int i=0; i<keyLen; ++i){
        int index = key[i]-'a';
        /*If i reaches the length of the string
        temp is turned to false is turned to false
        Which means if day word 'foo' is part of longer
        word 'football', 'foo' does not exist as a
        seperate word.
        And if only 'foo' exist in the dictionary,
        it also signals for it get removed in the next
        for loop.*/
        if(i==keyLen-1){
            temp->isWord = false;
        }
        temp = temp->children[index];
    }

    /*The pointer temp in the above for loop
    manages to reach to the end of the string
    Since, the previous pointer is being tracked
    it is easy to retract , if it is so required.*/
    for(int i=keyLen-1; i>=0; --i){

        /*If the temp isWord variable is false 
        and it happens to have not children
        then it is being removed. Not this removal
        happens in the bottom up fashion, which
        allows effective memory deletion.*/
        if(temp->isWord == false && hasNoChildren(temp)){
            node*p = temp;
            temp = temp->previous;
            delete p;
            }
            else temp= temp->previous;
        }
}


int main(){
    node* a = new node;
    string keys[] = { "the", "a", "there",
                      "answer", "any", "by",
                      "bye", "their", "hero", "heroplane" };
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        insert(a, keys[i]);
    search(a, "the") ? cout << "Yes\n" : cout << "No\n";
    search(a, "these") ? cout << "Yes\n" : cout << "No\n";
    remove(a,"heroplane");
    search(a, "hero") ? cout << "Yes\n" : cout << "No\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How much of this code was actually written by you?

Comment: I wrote the deletion portion, and I modified the search as well as insert function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your code is not consistently formatted:

   - Sometimes you have two empty lines before a function, sometimes none. Best to Always have exactly one.
   - I suggest also leaving an empty line after the includes, as well as before any class-/struct-/union-definition.
   - Sometimes you leave out the space between type and identifier.
   - Sometimes you surround a binary operator with spaces, sometimes you don't for the same one.
     I suggest one space on both sides for all but comma (`,`, leave a space after it) and member-access (`.` and `->`).
   - I'm not sure why you sometimes put single statements into their own blocks for a control-structure, and sometimes don't.
   - Space before a semicolon is very odd.
   - Your indentation also deserves some more TLC.
2. As the namespace `std` is not designed for being included wholesale, `using namespace std;` is a bug waiting to manifest. Read "[Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721)" for the details.
3. You use `std::string`, but you don't #include it. While any standard library header is allowed to include any others it likes, very few secondary includes are mandatory.
4. Using a `std::string_view` wherever you currently use a `std::string` would remove many useless short-term allocations.
5. Consider encapsulating your datastructure in its own class. That's what they are for!
6. You are assuming keys only contain lowercase latin characters (or the one directly following, which is `{` for ASCII). I assume the 27<sup>th</sup> Slot is wrong. Also, consider throwing a [`std::domain_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/domain_error) if you are wrong, and encapsulating the mapping in its own function.
7. You are using a single in-class-initializer, specifically for `isWord`. That leaves all the rest un-initialized, resulting in UB.
   Personally, I would remove it and value-initialize the whole node.
8. Three of four functions accept a `node*` by reference, assign it to a non-reference and forget it. I hope you see that's just wrong?
9. You only use `node::previous` for `remove()`. It's pretty trivial to remove that need by saving the last node which must be retained.
10. If you save the number of times a node is needed (children + endpoint), you can speed up testing for obsolescence considerably.
11. You don't notify the caller if a key already is (`insert()`) respectively is not (`remove()`) in the trie.
12. `search()` should be able to deal with a constant Version of the trie.
13. Consider adding `noexcept` and `constexpr` where appropriate.
14. Your comments rephrase the code, adding nothing useful. Explain the why, not the what, the latter being far better represented by the code.
15. While you should generally free all the resources you allocated, skipping it might be harmless at the end of the program for many of them. Anyway, think about how to free the whole datastructure.
16. `return 0;` is implicit for `main()`.

Modified code ([See live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/116ac74115de98b6)):

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string_view>
#include <utility>

struct node {
    bool terminal;
    unsigned char count;
    node* children[26];
};

constexpr static inline auto& child(const node* p, char c) {
    if (c < 'a' || c > 'z')
        throw std::domain_error("Must be a lowercase latin letter");
    return p->children[c - 'a'];
}
constexpr static inline auto& child(node* p, char c) {
    return const_cast<node*&>(child(const_cast<const node*>(p), c));
}

bool insert(node*& root, std::string_view key) {
    if (!root)
        root = new node();
    auto* p = root;
    for (auto c : key) {
        auto& x = child(p, c);
        if (!x) {
            x = new node();
            ++p->count;
        }
        p = x;
    }
    if (p->terminal)
        return false;
    p->terminal = true;
    ++p->count;
    return true;
}

bool search(const node* root, std::string_view key) noexcept
try {
    for (auto c : key) {
        if (!root)
            break;
        root = child(root, c);
    }
    return root && root->terminal;
} catch(std::domain_error&) {
    return false;
}

bool remove(node* root, std::string_view key) noexcept
try {
    auto p = root;
    if (!p)
        return false;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < key.size(); ++i) {
        p = child(p, key[i]);
        if (!p)
            return false;
        if (p->count > 1) {
            root = p;
            key = key.substr(i + 1);
            i = -1;
        }
    }
    if (!p->terminal)
        return false;
    --root->count;
    if (root == p) {
        root->terminal = false;
        return true;
    }
    p = std::exchange(child(root, key[0]), nullptr);
    key = key.substr(1);
    for (auto c : key)
        delete std::exchange(p, child(p, c));
    delete p;
    return true;
} catch(std::domain_error&) {
    return false;
}

void destroy(node* root) noexcept {
    if (!root)
        return;
    node* trees = nullptr;
    node* reserve = nullptr;
    root->count -= root->terminal;
    root->terminal = false;
    for (auto p = root, np = root; !reserve; p = np) {
        if (!root->count) {
            delete trees;
            delete root;
            return;
        }
        np = root;
        for (auto& x : p->children) {
            if (x && x->count == x->terminal) {
                --p->count;
                (!trees ? trees : reserve) = std::exchange(x, {});
                if (reserve)
                    break;
            } else if (x) {
                np = x;
            }
        }
    }

    auto trees_free = std::size(trees->children);
    trees->children[--trees_free] = nullptr;
    trees->children[--trees_free] = root;
    while ((root = trees->children[trees_free++])) {
        if (trees_free == std::size(root->children)) {
            delete std::exchange(reserve, trees);
            trees = root;
        } else
            for (auto x : root->children)
                if (x && x->count == x->terminal) {
                    delete std::exchange(reserve, x);
                } else if (x) {
                    if (!trees_free) {
                        trees_free = std::size(trees->children);
                        reserve->children[--trees_free] = trees;
                        trees = std::exchange(reserve, {});
                    }
                    trees->children[--trees_free] = x;
                }
    }
    delete trees;
    delete reserve;
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    node* a = nullptr;
    std::string_view keys[] = { "the", "a", "there", "answer", "any", "by",
        "bye", "their", "hero", "heroplane" };
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        insert(a, keys[i]);
    std::cout << (search(a, "the") ? "Yes\n" : "No\n");
    std::cout << (search(a, "these") ? "Yes\n" : "No\n");
    remove(a,"heroplane");
    std::cout << (search(a, "hero") ? "Yes\n" : "No\n");
    std::cout << (search(a, "heroplane") ? "Yes\n" : "No\n");
    destroy(a);
}
```

Comment: `You use std::string, but you don't #include it. While any standard library header is allowed to include any others it likes, very few secondary includes are mandatory.` For whatever reason, I was working on code recently, and in visual studio it let me use std::string while including <iostream>. So, it may not be technically be needed. However, I agree that it would be much clearer, and is not good to assume <iostream> includes string (even if it does).